# Save select sheets to HTML using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following VBA to save specific sheets.  I would like to save the sheets at HTML.  I tried changing the . xls to .html but all I get is gobby gook (technical term) Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit 

Sub TwoSheetsAndYourOut() 
    Dim NewName As String 
    Dim nm As Name 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 

    If MsgBox("Copy specific sheets to a new workbook" & vbCr & _ 
    "New sheets will be pasted as values, named ranges removed" _ 
    , vbYesNo, "NewCopy") = vbNo Then Exit Sub 

    With Application 
        .ScreenUpdating = False 

         '       Copy specific sheets
         '       *SET THE SHEET NAMES TO COPY BELOW*
         '       Array("Sheet Name", "Another sheet name", "And Another"))
         '       Sheet names go inside quotes, separated by commas
        On Error GoTo ErrCatcher 
        Sheets(Array("Copy Me", "Copy Me2")).Copy 
        On Error GoTo 0 

         '       Paste sheets as values
         '       Remove External Links, Hperlinks and hard-code formulas
         '       Make sure A1 is selected on all sheets
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
            ws.Cells.Copy 
            ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues 
            ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete 
            Application.CutCopyMode = False 
            Cells(1, 1).Select 
            ws.Activate 
        Next ws 
        Cells(1, 1).Select 

         '       Remove named ranges
        For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names 
            nm.Delete 
        Next nm 

         '       Input box to name new file
        NewName = InputBox("Please Specify the name of your new workbook", "New Copy") 

         '       Save it with the NewName and in the same directory as original
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewName & ".xls" 
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False 

        .ScreenUpdating = True 
    End With 
    Exit Sub 

ErrCatcher: 
    MsgBox "Specified sheets do not exist within this workbook" 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ron de Bruin's [RangetoHTML](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) code. Call it from within your `For Each ws...` loop

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewName & ".xls"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:**locationtosave**.html", FileFormat:=xlHtml`